# HTML5 input type time, when 00:00:00 value isn't completely there (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

So I have the following html input like so

```
<input id="time_in" type="time" step="1" name="duration">
```

And when I set the value in browser to "00:00:00" all seems good.

But then you jump into the console (or submit the form, etc.) the value is truncated to "00:00"

i.e. jquery

```
$("#time_in")[0].value == "00:00"
```

or plain js

```
document.getElementById("time_in").value == "00:00"
```

My question is what gives? Is this supposed to be the behavior?
This doesn't seem correct to me, does anyone know if I'm not setting an attribute or doing something non-standard?

edit:

if it makes any difference this is only with "00:00:00", when you set it to "00:00:01" it's correctly set and you can

```
document.getElementById("time_in").value == "00:00:01"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is standard-compliant behaviour, but so is `00:00:00`.

In the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#time-state-(type=time)):

> The `value` attribute, if specified and not empty, must have a value that is a valid time string.

Where a "[valid time string](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-time-string)" is:

> A string is a **valid time string** representing an hour `hour`, a minute `minute`, and a second `second` if it consists of the following components in the given order:
>
> 1. Two ASCII digits, representing hour, in the range 0 ≤ `hour` ≤ 23
> 2. A ":" (U+003A) character
> 3. Two ASCII digits, representing minute, in the range 0 ≤ `minute` ≤ 59
> 4. Optionally (required if `second` is non-zero):
>
>    1. A ":" (U+003A) character
>    2. Two ASCII digits, representing the integer part of `second`, in the range 0 ≤ `s` ≤ 59
>    3. Optionally (required if `second` is not an integer):
>
>       1. A 002E FULL STOP character (.)
>       2. One, two, or three ASCII digits, representing the fractional part of `second`
>
> **Note:** The `second` component cannot be 60 or 61; leap seconds cannot be represented.

Therefore, the last bit after the minute (including the colon) is optional if the second is zero, but not prohibited.

Comment: hmm okay, so basically when it's 00:00 I'll need to just assume it's valid. In that case I guess I can set it as "00:00:00" if needed.

Thanks